# Am getting Unknown property 'Pageniation.FeedbackFrom__c' error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom

I am trying to Create Wizard for Custom Object

Here is my Apex Code:

```
public class Pageniation {
public FeedbackFrom__c Fed{get;set;}

 public FeedbackFrom__c getFed() {
      if(Fed== null) Fed = new FeedbackFrom__c();
      return Fed;
   }
    public PageReference step1() {
      return Page.Newtest;
   }

   public PageReference step2() {
      return Page.Newtest2;
   }

   public PageReference step3() {
      return Page.Newtest3;
   }
 public PageReference cancel() {
            PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
            FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);
            return FeedbackPage; 
    }
public PageReference save() {

PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
      FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);

      return FeedbackPage;
   }

}
```

Here is my VF Code:

```
<apex:page controller="Pageniation" tabStyle="FeedbackFrom__c">
  <script>
  function confirmCancel() {
      var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
      if (isCancel) return true;

     return false;
  }  
  </script>
  <apex:sectionHeader title="New Customer Opportunity" subtitle="Step 1 of 3"/>
    <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlock title="Customer Information" mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Next"/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" 
                              onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="FeedBack">
     <apex:inputField id="myPicklist" required="true" value="{!FeedbackFrom__c.X2_Are_you_Satisfied_with_our_production__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But am Getting Unknown property 'Pageniation.FeedbackFrom__c' error please help me out from this issue.

Comment: It's `Fed` not `FeedbackFrom__c`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use instance references in the Visualforce page, not the object type.

So when you do `<apex:inputField id="myPicklist" required="true" value="{!FeedbackFrom__c.X2_Are_you_Satisfied_with_our_production__c}"/>`, the visualforce page could not find any instance with name `FeedbackFrom__c` in the controller.

You have an instance named - `fed` which is of type `FeedbackFrom__c`, so you should use `fed.X2_Are_you_Satisfied_with_our_production__c` instead of `FeedbackFrom__c.X2_Are_you_Satisfied_with_our_production__c`.

What @itszmukeshy commented is correct, I just thought there should be an explanation.